# Random † appears while editing in Text Edit

Tags: javascript, textedit

I'm new to Macs and was editing my .js in text edit.  I don't know when this happened but...4

†

appeared in my text.  I don't even know how to make that symbol...I just copy pasted it over from Text Edit in to SO.

1. What is this?
2. Where did it come from?

I don't do anything weird in my text editing...just typing and some copy pasting.

Comment: [`MAC` is not an acronym, it's an abbreviation](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/fasterforward/2010/10/postpoints_tip_mac_is_not_an_a.html) :)

Comment: TextEdit uses (Apple's version of) RTF by default. Really don't recommend editing source code in it. Better to use something like [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) if you need a free solution.

Comment: For your information, this symbol is made pressing `ALT+ 0134` †

Comment: I normally don't pay attention to my text editor..which is not a good idea...IE9 won't run b.c. it is detecting some kind of unicode character in my text as well...

Comment: @Ghillied....hitting 5 characters at once?

Comment: @Ghillied: that's true on Windows only. Macs have a different way of printing it, and various *nix flavors have all sorts of ways to print it, I'm sure.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: No, it's "hold down the Alt key, press 0, 1, 3, 4, release Alt key." And it's specifically the numbers on the numpad, not the ones above the keyboard.

Comment: never new....alt T does it as well on Mac keyboard

Comment: This may be interesting: http://alt-codes.org/mac/
`option + T` = †

I would suggest getting a code editor. A good free one(IMO) is Sublime Text 2, but this is my personal opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That character is the [dagger symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_%28typography%29) and is usually used to denote a non-printable character such as space, tab, line feed, etc. What it means in your particular text editor, I am not sure.

Comment: +1 for character definition. I'll know what it means if it gets to happen to me.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have pressed alt/option T?

Alt/option on a mac keyboard is used for typing special characters in addition to its usual role as a meta key. You can see its effect more easily with [the keyboard viewer](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2896/mac_os_x_use_the_keyboard_viewer_to_identify_special_character_keystrokes/) palette.

Comment: there were 4 in a vertical line though

Comment: Alt and option are the same key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a form feed char (`\f` in c). Some editors may use `\n\f` (line feed, form feed) for new lines. Your editor may only be expecting `\n`.

Comment: Line feed is `\n`. Carriage return is `\r`. Form feed is `\f`.